# regex match first occurrence of dot and any following backslash

Tags: regex

I'm trying to take a string like this:

```
.block\.customcategory\.image\.link
```

... or

```
#block\.customcategory\.image\.link
```

and strip the leading dot/pound and all subsequent  backslashes:

```
block.customcategory.image.link
```

I can get only as far as `/^[\.#]/gm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leading dot/pound:

```
/^[.#]/          <-- at start of string (in most languages)
/^[.#]/m         <-- at start of line
```

Backslash:

```
/\\/g
```

Leading dot/pound *or* backslash:

```
/(^[.#]|\\)/g
/(^[.#]|\\)/gm
```

Comment: Think you have your back/forward slashes mixed up

Comment: @rrrr: I did indeed; dunno how that happened. Fixed now, thank you!

Comment: @rrrr I think the original poster does.

Comment: @tchrist I can't see any problems in the question? The only forward slashes I see are in the construction of the regex which is par for the course in JavaScript. The answer has been edited to fix those problems now anyway.

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day (or a couple), literally!

Comment: @rrrr I was teasing.  People who put backslashes in paths instead of proper slashes probably have other unsocial habits as well, like omitting newlines at the ends of their textfiles or putting BOMs at their fronts. Ç:-)

Comment: @tchrist: Who said anything about backslashes *in paths*?

Comment: @ruakh Well, that’s what the OP looked like to me.

Comment: @tchrist: I don't see why. Take another look at the OP's original string, and at the desired string. Do you still genuinely think that the backslashes are meant as path separators?